# Can FindSequenceFunction work on subscripts/superscripts?

Tags: digit-sequences

I am trying to find a pattern 'encoded' into variables with superscript labels, which incidentally look much like exponents. `FindSequenceFunction` though doesn't seem to care about even simple patterns.

This doesn't work:

```
FindSequenceFunction[Table[Superscript[x,n],{n,1,6}]]
```

Even if it's syntactically identical to

```
FindSequenceFunction[Table[Power[x,n],{n,1,6}]]
```

Is there way to extend `FindSequenceFunction` to work on indices?

Comment: I think not but they’re always improving things. I think it uses (mathematical) analytic methods to determine a formula. For instance Power has special properties such as a constant ratio between successive terms. I think its algorithms are built on such analytical properties. “Holonomic” is a broad class of functions it can handle. Conceivably it could be extended to handle symbolic patterns involving non mathematical functions but I don’t think it has been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly can if the downvalues of `Superscript` comprise a sequence it can deal with. Here is an example.

```
Clear[Superscript]
Do[Superscript[x, i] = i^2, {i, 6}];
DownValues @ Superscript
```

[image: downvals]

Then

```
FindSequenceFunction[Table[Superscript[x, n], {n, 6}]]
```

> `#1^2 &`